# Writing Spark Dataset with Custom Unix Group

Tags: java, apache-spark, unix, hadoop, parquet

In apache spark, I'm having a dataset which I'm writing to disk:

```
var ds = Seq(1, 2, 3).toDS();

ds.write.parquet("/tmp/01/01");
```

As expected, this writes records on disk in parquet format:

```
vaxaci$ ls -ltr /tmp/01/01/
total 24
drwxr-----  1 vaxaci  hadoop  430 Oct 19 14:12 part-00000-ba320358-7ee3-46dc-b90f-3b9c94fa6503-c000.snappy.parquet
drwxr-----  1 vaxaci  hadoop  430 Oct 19 14:12 part-00001-ba320358-7ee3-46dc-b90f-3b9c94fa6503-c000.snappy.parquet
drwxr-----  1 vaxaci  hadoop  430 Oct 19 14:12 part-00002-ba320358-7ee3-46dc-b90f-3b9c94fa6503-c000.snappy.parquet
drwxr-----  1 vaxaci  hadoop    0 Oct 19 14:12 _SUCCESS
```

But the problem is with the UNIX group with which it's writing. Currently it is writing with group name `hadoop`.

Is there any way through which I can programatically (in `java` preferably) modify this group to something else, say `friends`?

Comment: I don't think that's possible but a solution might be to write the file with the "hadoop" group then change the permission in Java or Python.